# why is my state variable undefined for props.location.state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am transferring data from one page to another using Link. I can get the data on the new page as well which I am checking using a console. The problem is, I am not able to set the initial state variable using this data using useState. Below is my code.

```
export default function myFunc(props) {
 
  const { myData, setMyData } = useState(props.location.state);
  // const { myData, setMyData } = useState({...props.location.state}); // This doesn't work either
  console.log('props here', props.location.state); // see the required object
  console.log('myData here', myData); // get undefined instead of the required object
```

Why am I getting undefined for myData?

Comment: You should  be using array destructuring:  `const [ myData, setMyData ]`

Comment: @NickParsons: You are correct, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use rectangular bracket in useState declaration and use `useEffect` hook to show `myData` initial value. Something like:

```
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState(props.location.state);
  console.log('props here', props.location.state);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myData);
  },[myData])
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using the wrong brackets.